# CPT Template Option to Top

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, metabox

I edited the following core file because I was unable to make the change in my child theme. I need my CPT Template option to appear first in the Post Attributes -- Template drop down list. I made it happen by editing: .../wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php, within the "default_page_template_title" filter.

I switched the order of two lines making my CPT Template appear on TOP.

```
<?php page_template_dropdown( $template, $post->post_type ); ?>
<option value="default"><?php echo esc_html( $default_title ); ?></option>
</select>
```

How would I do this in the child theme?

Thank you

Comment: what core file did you edit?

Comment: I edited:  .../wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php around line 896

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hook into [theme_{$post_type}_templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_theme/get_page_templates/) and add an identical "default" option at the end:

```
add_action('theme_page_templates', 'wpse_296283_theme_page_templates');
function wpse_296283_theme_page_templates($post_templates){
  $post_templates['default'] = "Default Template";  
  return $post_templates;  
}
```

Then you'd hide the first one with CSS:

```
add_action('admin_head' 'wpse_296283_admin_head');
function wpse_296283_admin_head(){
  ?>
  <style>#page_template option:first-child {display: none;}</style>
  <?php
}
```

Comment: Was hoping for a server side solution, but a slight variation of your input solved things for now.  Thank you Josue.